# I can't automatically connect to bluetooth device from the command line in Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, lubuntu

I recently changed OS on an old laptop from Ubuntu to Lubuntu for better performance. On Ubuntu, I had a script that ran on startup to automatically connect to my electric drumkit for bluetooth audio.

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth

sleep 15

bluetoothctl connect E0:B8:36:20:AA:35
```

This was my script. However, it doesn't work on Lubuntu.

Lubuntu has bluetooth disabled on startup, and the Bluetooth Device Wizard shows this like so:

[image: Default status of Bluetooth Device Wizard at startup]

When I run `rfkill unblock bluetooth` , the Bluetooth Device Wizard changes to this:

[image: Bluetooth Device Wizard after running rfkill unblock bluetooth]

As you can see, I have this new barrier that I didn't have with Ubuntu. I can't use bluetoothctl at this point to connect to the device like I did in Ubuntu, and if I try, I get `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotReady`.

So far, I can't find a command which does the same as clicking the 'make pairable' button.

If I click 'enable bluetooth' or 'make pairable' from the Bluetooth Device Wizard, I am able to connect ok using the command line, so the problem isn't with anything to do with bluetoothctl or the device not being trusted or paired correctly.

I am able to connect with the GUI, but the point is, I need it to connect automatically on startup without the GUI.

Does anyone know how I can properly enable bluetooth from the command line in Lubuntu? How can I 'make pairable' from the command line?

And help would be greatly appreciated. There isn't a lot of info online about Lubuntu unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it solved using `systemctl restart bluetooth` after `rfkill unblock bluetooth`.

My script is now:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
sleep 5
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sleep 15
bluetoothctl connect 34:81:F4:99:77:ED
sleep 5
bluetoothctl connect 34:81:F4:99:77:ED
```

I don't know why I have to connect twice, but I do.

Answer (score 0):

In shell script, `bluetoothctl` command should be executed with `--`:

```
bluetoothctl -- power on
sleep 1
bluetoothctl -- pair E0:B8:36:20:AA:35
sleep 2
bluetoothctl -- connect E0:B8:36:20:AA:35
```

Comment: ```bluetoothctl connect E0:B8:36:20:AA:35``` works fine. It’s not that I can’t connect, the problem is I can’t enable bluetooth first to be able to use the bluetoothctl commands.